# Dropdown value not registering in template driven forms

Tags: angular

I have a select dropdown in template driven forms, whose value is coming dynamically using *ngFor:

```
<form class="col-md-5 location-seachform" name="loctionForm" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f);" novalidate  >
   <select class="form-control" name="somename" ngModel >
     <option [value]="ii" [attr.selected]="ii==0 ? '' : null" *ngFor="let loc_crit of objectKeys(somecriteria); let ii= index"> {{somecriteria[loc_crit] }} 
     </option>
   <select>
<button class="btn btn--filled pull-right" type="submit"><span class="btn__copy"><span class="btn__label">Search</span></span></button>
</form>
```

NOw the problem is that both dropdown and the object I am console-logging on click of the submit button is not showing the default value of the select, even though I have used

`[attr.selected]="ii==0 ? '' : null"`

and the first option is showing in the chrome debugger as selected, but still, the first option is not selected by default. The object showing on the click of the submit button is also not showing the default value. The object is like this:

`{somename:''}`

whereas it should come as 

`{somename:'firstValue'}`

Comment: Add you ts also.

Comment: Try consolo.log on change event. (
<select class="form-control" name="somename" change)="onChange($event)" ngModel >

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[(ngModel)]="selected"`

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ya4dk1?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

.ts

```
selected = this.somecriteria[Object.keys(this.somecriteria)[0]];

objectKeys(data) {
  return Object.keys(data);
}

onFormSubmit(formValue) {
  console.log(formValue);
}
```

.html

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(myForm.value)">
    <select class="form-control" name="somename" [(ngModel)]="selected" >
    <option  *ngFor="let loc_crit of objectKeys(somecriteria); let ii= index"> 
       {{somecriteria[loc_crit] }} 
    </option>
</select>
    <button class="btn btn--filled pull-right" type="submit"><span class="btn__copy"><span class="btn__label">Search</span></span></button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular forms looks only at the formcontrol value, in this case you have registered your formcontrol with value `""` (empty string), so such a value does not exist in your data. You can solve this by setting `[ngModel]="0"` if you want the first option to be pre-selected. Also you need to change `[value]` to `[ngValue]`, as `value` captures only strings, while `ngValue` accepts numbers, objects. Unless of course you **want** it to be a string, then use `[ngModel]="'0'"`. So all in all, do (first option):

```html
<select name="somename" [ngModel]="0">
 <option [ngValue]="ii" *ngFor="let loc_crit of objectKeys(somecriteria); let ii = index"> 
   {{somecriteria[loc_crit] }} 
 </option>
</select>
```